# UITableViewCell Custom Image Size, Shadow And Borders

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Following is the image i have taken from an app from the App Store:

[image: UITableViewCell]

I have created an app that is using StoryBoard with custom tableview cell. The data is loaded in it from a web service. This is what i want:

**1)** How can i change the size of the uitableviewcell according to the image? For example if one image is 640*500, then the UITableViewCell will change its size accordingly. If the size if the image is 640*1000, then the cell should change its size accordingly.

**2)** How can i add the grey coloured border around the tableview cells just like in the image above?

**3)** How can i add a shadow dropping from the UITableViewCell just like in the image above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently i have a partial answer to your question. Part 2 of the question that is the colored border can be solved by the following code:

```
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:222/255.0f green:222/255.0f blue:222/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:5.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Part-1
The height of the tableviewcell is determined using

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   /*
    Get the image size 
    CGFloat width = myImage.size.width;
    CGFloat height = myImage.size.height;
    use this to return the height of your cell. 
   */
}
```

Part-2 and Part-3
Use..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //This will give you access to the cell being rendered and any customization you want can be done here... You can use the earlier answer for this part.. I havent tried it but should work..
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Do i need to change the UIImageView size first then the height of the cell?

Comment: Return the height taking into account the size of the UIImageView, then you can manually set the frame of the UIImageView inside cellForRowAtIndexPath